# Reaching access Reports from C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ms-access-2007

I have created a report in microsoft access database

And now i want to use it in my project but i weren't able to find any thing online

What i want to do is

Populating the report with data and print it without of showing any thing in the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to automate Microsoft Access by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/317114/how-to-automate-microsoft-access-by-using-visual-c) article on MS Support site describes how to automate Access actions with C#.

See **Print or Preview an Access Report** section for your issue.

> To preview or to print an Access report, you call the OpenReport
>   method of the DoCmd object. When you call OpenReport, one of the
>   arguments that you pass determines whether the report is previewed on
>   the screen, or whether it is sent to the printer:
>
> ```
> // Preview a report named Sales:
> oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport(
>     "Sales", //ReportName
>     Access.AcView.acViewPreview, //View
>     System.Reflection.Missing.Value, //FilterName
>     System.Reflection.Missing.Value //WhereCondition
> );
> ```

According to MS doc, with the 4th parameter you should be able to pass a :

> A string expression that's a valid SQL WHERE clause without the word WHERE

For exemple, if you want to show the report for the record ID 292, simply replace `System.Reflection.Missing.Value //WhereCondition` by `"ID=292"`

AFAIK it's not possible to populate reports fields directly from C# code.

Comment: Could you please add the key points of the article in your answer? Because it is possible, that the article will be deleted in future

Comment: I have found some code      but i can't understand a part of it                                         what does it mean when it says              *  System.Reflection.Missing.Value  *     all i want is passing the parameters to the report and it will do the rest         i mean if i double clicked it from access directly it will ask me for more inputs     how can i reach those inputs from code     oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport(
"Sales", //ReportName
Access.AcView.acViewPreview, //View
System.Reflection.Missing.Value, //FilterName
System.Reflection.Missing.Value //WhereCondition
);

Comment: I will test it and i will be back